# How to combine two Text Views in SwiftUI that have different formatting

Tags: swiftui

I can combine two text views like this.

```swift
Text("1") + Text("1")
```

But how can I do something like this?

```swift
Text("1") + Text("1").border(Color.red)
```

I cant simply do this

```
HStack(spacing: 0) { 
    Text("1")
    Text("1").border(Color.red) 
}
```

because the design will behave differently as seen below
[image]

They will behave as 2 separate texts. I want the one on the right to wrap around, so that both Texts looks like a single text.

Comment: Could you please check this -> `Text("1") + Text("1").border(.red)`

Comment: Next time be more precise in your formulations.

Answer (score 0):

operator `+` could be applied if both operands are the same type (`Text` in your case).

```
struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Text("A").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(Color.red) + Text("B").font(.title) + Text("C").font(.footnote)
    }
}
```

gives you

[image]

which is exactly one Text again, just because `.font` or `.foreground` modifier could return `Text` if applied on `Text`.

`.border` modifier returns `View`, that is why it doesn't work in your example.

Comment: But is there a way to add a background color to one of those texts?

Comment: yes, just calculate each size, and make  background View as composition of different rectangles ... be inspired here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832193/how-to-get-position-of-each-character-in-swiftui-text