# How to draw text along circular path using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, watchos

I need some help on how to generate a single line text in a circular path using SwiftUI. I am trying to replicate the curved text in these [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lChRW.png). Is this possible in SwiftUI? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw text along circular path in Swift for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios)

Comment: There's no easy built-in way. Tobias Due Munk talks about putting text along a circle starting around 9m20s in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BHHybRnHFE). His code [may be available soon](https://twitter.com/tobiasdm/status/1227762331742015488). Rob Napier's [CurvyText](https://github.com/rnapier/CurvyText) project might also be helpful.

Comment: Another solution can be found in answer to this question: [SwiftUI: How to have equal spacing between letters in a curved text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77277211/20386264)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]Found a solution to my question. Credits to Tobias Due Munk for posting his prototype for CurvedText using SwiftUI. His solution can be found here https://github.com/duemunk/CrookedText

Example usage:

`CrookedText(text: "Hello, world!", radius: 10)`

Comment: https://git.kabellmunk.dk/prototyping-custom-ui-in-swiftui-talk/custom-ui-prototype-in-swiftui/-/blob/master/Custom%20UI%20Prototype/Prototype/CurvedText.swift

Comment: I believe Tobias moved the code here: https://github.com/duemunk/CrookedText

Answer (score 1):

No, Swift UI doesn't provide any way to do that as of now. So as @fulvio pointed out you must do it [Swift UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios) way .

You can later use UIViewRepresentable to integrate it in your SwiftUI Project
[Refer Swift UI interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) by Apple Inc.

Comment: I tried doing it as UIViewRepresentable but UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() doesnt seem to be supported in SwiftUI.

Comment: Then I guess you can't but there isn't any Swift ui way for sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. **calculate position of each character**, see [How to get position of each character in SwiftUI Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832193/how-to-get-position-of-each-character-in-swiftui-text) and related answers and discussions, to know the limitations
2. **calculate required position and rotation** of each character on the path you would like to follow (for circle it is very easy to be done) with help of step 1 (use the distance along the path as a parameter)
3. **position and rotate each character** as here [Positioning View using anchor point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272419/positioning-view-using-anchor-point/59481599#59481599)

I know that ***answers with links***, as already mentioned by "Ru Chem Chong", *is not the best*, but answer your question is really complex task and explanation needs more than space available here.