# SwiftUI: How to have equal spacing between letters in a curved text view?

Tags: swiftui, textview

I'm drawing a curved text view, where I would like the spacing between each of the letters to be equal.

So far, I tried updating the font to `.font(.system(size: 14, design: .monospaced))` which gives me equal spacing between the letters, but its not the correct font.

Currently, the spacing looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, I would like the spacing to look like this (with the correct custom font):

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var letterWidths: [Int: Double] = [:]
    private let title = "AVENIRNEXT"

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(Array(title.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, letter in
                VStack {
                    Text(String(letter))
                        .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14))
                        .kerning(3)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in // using this to get the width of each letter
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: LetterWidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                        value: geometry.size.width
                                    )
                            }
                        )
                        .onPreferenceChange(LetterWidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { width in
                            letterWidths[index] = width
                        })
                    Spacer()
                }
                .rotationEffect(fetchAngle(at: index))
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300 * 0.75)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(335))
        }
    }

    func fetchAngle(at letterPosition: Int) -> Angle {
        let timesPi: (Double) -> Double = { $0 * .pi }

        let radius: Double = 125
        let circumference = timesPi(radius)

        let finalAngle = timesPi(
            letterWidths
                .filter { $0.key < letterPosition }
                .map(\.value)
                .reduce(0, +) / circumference
        )
        return .radians(finalAngle)
    }

}

struct LetterWidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Double = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout Double, nextValue: () -> Double) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite an impressive effort, trying to assemble the final effect out of individual letters. But I wonder if you wouldn't be better off generating an image of the text you want, then displaying that, rearranged in the way you need? If there's no interaction between the user and the text, then I'd look into that. (See ImageRenderer for generating image, and maybe some Metal shaders for distorting result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you that uses overlays and `GeometryReader` to get the frame size of the base text and also to get the frame size and relative position of each character in the text. With this information, it is possible to compute the required angle and offset for each character.

What I noticed is that when you use an `HStack` to put together individual characters to form some text, the spacing does not exactly match what you get when the text is formed from a single string. However, it's a pretty close approximation. Also, I found that kerning works, even when building up the string using individual characters. So the spacing for the `HStack` can always be 0.

The curved result is always centered around the vertical axis, so if you need it to be displayed at a different angle, just rotate the whole result.

```swift
struct CurvedText: View {
    let string: String
    let radius: CGFloat

    var body: some View {

        // Build the text as single characters, hidden
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(string.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, character in
                Text(String(character))
            }
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .hidden()
        .overlay {
            GeometryReader { fullText in
                let textWidth = fullText.size.width
                let arcAngle = radius == 0 ? 0 : (textWidth / radius)
                let startAngle = -(arcAngle / 2)

                // Build the text using single characters again
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(Array(string.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, character in

                        // Each character in the HStack is hidden
                        Text(String(character))
                            .hidden()
                            .overlay {

                                // Overlay with the same character, this time
                                // visible and with rotation and offset
                                GeometryReader { charSpace in
                                    let midX = charSpace.frame(in: .named("FullText")).midX
                                    let fraction = midX / textWidth
                                    let angle = startAngle + (fraction * arcAngle)
                                    let xOffset = (textWidth / 2) - midX
                                    Text(String(character))
                                        .offset(y: -radius)
                                        .rotationEffect(.radians(angle))
                                        .offset(x: xOffset, y: radius)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: textWidth)
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "FullText")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CurvedText(
                string: "The quick brown fox",
                radius: 120
            )

            CurvedText(
                string: "jumps over the lazy dog",
                radius: 120
            )
            .font(.footnote)

            ZStack {
                CurvedText(
                    string: "AvenirNext-DemiBold",
                    radius: 100
                )
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14))
                .kerning(3)
                .padding(.leading, 150)
                .padding(.bottom, 75)

                CurvedText(
                    string: "AvenirNext-DemiBold",
                    radius: 100
                )
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14))
                .kerning(3)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .padding(.trailing, 150)
            }
            .padding(.top, 100)
            .padding(.trailing, 75)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: CurvedText]

*EDIT* For more examples of how to use `CurvedText`, see [How to create equal spacing between letters in a curved text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77285416/20386264)