# How to create equal spacing between letters in a curved text view?

Tags: swiftui, textview

I'm drawing a curved text view centered in an arc shape, where I would like the spacing between each of the letters to be equal.

I tried updating the text font to `.font(.system(size: 14, design: .monospaced))` which gives me equal spacing between the letters, but its not the correct font.

Currently, the spacing looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, this is what it should look like (but with the correct font):

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var letterWidths: [Int: Double] = [:]
    private let size: CGFloat = 300

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ArcShape(start: 180, end: 230)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            textView("AVENIR", start: 180, end: 230)

            ArcShape(start: 233, end: 300)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            textView("DEMIBOLD", start: 233, end: 300)
        }
        .frame(width: size)
    }

    func textView(_ title: String, start: CGFloat, end: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            let firstLetterAngle = calculateLetterAngle(at: 0)
            let lastLetterAngle = calculateLetterAngle(at: title.count - 1)
            let titleAngleDifference: Angle = lastLetterAngle - firstLetterAngle

            let segmentAngleDifference: Angle = .degrees(end) - .degrees(start)

            let titleOffsetAngle = (segmentAngleDifference - titleAngleDifference) / 2

            ForEach(Array(title.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, letter in
                VStack {
                    Text(String(letter))
                        .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14))
                        .kerning(3)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in // using this to get the width of each letter
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: LetterWidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                        value: geometry.size.width
                                    )
                            }
                        )
                        .onPreferenceChange(LetterWidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { width in
                            letterWidths[index] = width
                        })
                    Spacer()
                }
                .rotationEffect(calculateLetterAngle(at: index))
            }
            // to center title in arc shape
            .frame(width: size, height: size * 0.75)
            .rotationEffect(titleOffsetAngle + .degrees(start) + .degrees(90))
        }
    }

    private func calculateLetterAngle(at letterPosition: Int) -> Angle {
        let times2Pi: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = { $0 * 2 * .pi }

        let radius: CGFloat = 125
        let circumference = times2Pi(radius)

        let letterAngle = times2Pi(
            letterWidths
                .filter { $0.key < letterPosition }
                .map(\.value)
                .reduce(0, +) / circumference
        )

        return .degrees(letterAngle * (180 / .pi)) // to convert radians to degrees
    }

}

struct LetterWidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Double = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout Double, nextValue: () -> Double) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    public convenience init(roundedArcCenter center: CGPoint, innerRadius: CGFloat, outerRadius: CGFloat, startAngle: Angle, endAngle: Angle, cornerRadiusPercentage: CGFloat) {
        let maxCornerRadiusBasedOnInnerArcLength = abs((endAngle - startAngle).radians) * innerRadius / 2
        let maxCornerRadiusBasedOnOuterArcLength = abs((endAngle - startAngle).radians) * outerRadius / 2
        let maxCornerRadiusBasedOnEndCapLength = (outerRadius - innerRadius) / 2
        let outerCornerRadius = min(2 * .pi * outerRadius * cornerRadiusPercentage, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnOuterArcLength, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnEndCapLength)
        let outerCornerRadiusPercentage = outerCornerRadius / (2 * .pi * outerRadius)
        let innerCornerRadius = min(2 * .pi * innerRadius * outerCornerRadiusPercentage, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnInnerArcLength, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnEndCapLength)
        let innerInsetAngle = Angle(radians: innerCornerRadius / innerRadius)
        let outerInsetAngle = Angle(radians: outerCornerRadius / outerRadius)
        self.init()
        var arcStartAngle = (startAngle + outerInsetAngle).radians
        var arcEndAngle = (endAngle - outerInsetAngle).radians
        addArc(
            withCenter: .zero,
            radius: outerRadius,
            startAngle: min(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            endAngle: max(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            clockwise: true
        )
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius - outerCornerRadius, angle: endAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius, angle: endAngle)
        )
        addLine(to: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius + innerCornerRadius, angle: endAngle))
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius, angle: endAngle - innerInsetAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius, angle: endAngle)
        )
        arcStartAngle = (endAngle - innerInsetAngle).radians
        arcEndAngle = (startAngle + innerInsetAngle).radians
        addArc(
            withCenter: .zero,
            radius: innerRadius,
            startAngle: max(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            endAngle: min(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            clockwise: false
        )
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius + innerCornerRadius, angle: startAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius, angle: startAngle)
        )
        addLine(to: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius - outerCornerRadius, angle: startAngle))
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius, angle: startAngle + outerInsetAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius, angle: startAngle)
        )
        apply(.init(translationX: center.x, y: center.y))
    }

    private func addCorner(to: CGPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint) {
        let circleApproximationConstant = 0.551915
        addCurve(
            to: to,
            controlPoint1: currentPoint + (controlPoint - currentPoint) * circleApproximationConstant,
            controlPoint2: to + (controlPoint - to) * circleApproximationConstant
        )
    }

}
private extension CGPoint {
    static func pointOnCircle(radius: CGFloat, angle: Angle) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: radius * Darwin.cos(angle.radians), y: radius * Darwin.sin(angle.radians))
    }
    static func + (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }
    static func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
    static func * (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x * rhs, y: lhs.y * rhs)
    }
}
public extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.0, y: size.height / 2.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: [Didn't you ask this yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77277211/5133585) How is this question different from the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking this question, because it is not clear how to use the [solution for curved text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77280669/20386264) that I provided in answer to your other question yesterday?

Like this:

```swift
var textRadius: CGFloat {
    size * 0.36
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ArcShape(start: 180, end: 230)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        CurvedText(string: "AVENIR", radius: textRadius)
            .offset(y: -textRadius)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(((180 + 230) / 2) + 90))

        ArcShape(start: 233, end: 300)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        CurvedText(string: "DEMIBOLD", radius: textRadius)
            .offset(y: -textRadius)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(((233 + 300) / 2) + 90))
    }
    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14))
    .kerning(3)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .frame(width: size)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes, I was having trouble centering the curved text in the shape with the previous solution and given this I realized its because I was missing the negative offset. Thank you so much for answering again, this is really helpful!

For future reference, would it have been better if I posted additional context in the previous question instead of creating a new question with additional context?

Comment: Yes, it might have been simpler to post a comment to the other solution, or at least explain in the question here why you were asking again. Never mind. BTW, you could change a line in ```CurvedText``` from ```.offset(x: xOffset, y: radius)``` to just ```.offset(x: xOffset)```. Then you could take out the negative offset being used here. I didn't provide it that way because I thought it might be confusing if the curved text was offset from the position in the layout where it is used. But for your purpose, it would probably make it easier to use.

Comment: Thank you, noted for next time! Ah okay, that's a good idea, I appreciate the help!

Comment: This is [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314117/how-to-determine-the-angle-of-the-first-character-in-a-curved-text-view-in-swift) is somewhat tied to your solution - I wanted to post it here in case you had any ideas