# How to draw circle stroke with rounded border

Tags: swiftui

I would like to draw a circle in SwiftUI where its border has subtle rounded corners. I think the picture is worth more than a 1000 words in this case.

[image]

So far I'm able to draw circles with "straight" corners as follows:

```swift
let gradient = AngularGradient(
      gradient: Gradient(colors: [color2, color1]),
      center: .center,
      startAngle: .degrees(0),
      endAngle: .degrees(endFraction*360))

ZStack {
  Circle()
    .stroke(lineWidth: 12)
    .foregroundColor(.darkSelect)
  
  Circle()
    .trim(from: 0, to: endFraction)
    .stroke(gradient, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: .butt))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
  Circle()
    .trim(from: 0, to: endFraction2)
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: .butt))
    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.15))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
}
```

However, the effect is obviously not what is intended in the design. I was wondering if there's any way in SwiftUI to style the stroke/circle in this way, or shall I just go with custom path entirely?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no `LineCap` style that provides this kind of effect for free. Here are some approaches that you could consider instead.

**1. Use different line caps and different frame sizes**

It might work to build up each segment using multiple strokes with different line caps and different frame sizes. For example, if you want to have a total stroke width of 12 with a corner radius of 2 then you could try:

- 1 x lineWidth of 4 with line cap `.round` and inset of 4
- 1 x lineWidth of 4 with line cap `.round` and inset of -4
- 1 x lineWidth of 8 with line cap `.butt`

However, there may be a number of complications with this approach:

- The first circle would need to be drawn as a segment too, not as a complete circle.
- If you wanted a gap between the joins, say 2 pt, then this will be difficult. You could subtract a small angle from the ends, but this will give a gap that is wedge shaped, not a regular line.
- It may not work if you stroke the segments using a gradient instead of a solid color, or if you use colors with partial transparency.

**2. Create a shape for a segment**

A safer approach would be to create your own shape for the segments, as you were suggesting. But computing the positions for the arcs on the corners may be tricky, especially if you want a regular gap between the segments.

See [How to create equal spacing between letters in a curved text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77284644/20386264) for an example of where a shape like this is already being used.

**3. Paint the joins in the background color**

If the background color is solid (that is, not a gradient) then another way to do it would be to use a shape like an `I` (with serifs) to paint over the joins using the background color. This may in fact be the easiest way to achieve the effect.

Here is a shape with this form:

```swift
struct ArcJoin: Shape {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        var x = rect.midX - cornerRadius
        var y = rect.minY
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        y += cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(-90),
            endAngle: .zero,
            clockwise: false
        )
        y = rect.maxY - cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .zero,
            endAngle: .degrees(90),
            clockwise: false
        )
        x = rect.midX + cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(90),
            endAngle: .degrees(180),
            clockwise: false
        )
        y = rect.minY + cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(180),
            endAngle: .degrees(270),
            clockwise: false
        )
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

This is how the shape looks when stroked with a lineWidth of 1:

[image: ArcJoin]

The example below is an adapted version of your example to show how it can be used. I found it worked better to stroke the shape, rather than filling it. Doing it this way, you need to use a linewidth that is thick enough to fill the corners (the corner radius can be made smaller if necessary). Alternatively, you could stroke and fill, of course.

The height given to the shape needs to be the width of the main circle stroke + the width of the shape stroke, so 12 + 2 = 14 in this example:

```swift
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .stroke(lineWidth: 12)
        .foregroundColor(darkSelect)
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0, to: endFraction)
        .stroke(mediumSelect, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: .butt))
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0, to: endFraction2)
        .stroke(lightSelect, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: .butt))
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
    
    ArcJoin()
        .stroke(bgColor, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(height: 14)
        .offset(y: -50) // the circle radius
    ArcJoin()
        .stroke(bgColor, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(height: 14)
        .offset(y: -50)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(endFraction * 360))
    ArcJoin()
        .stroke(bgColor, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(height: 14)
        .offset(y: -50)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(endFraction2 * 360))
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(bgColor)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Answer updated with descriptions of other alternative approaches.